# Connect attribut from csv to shape with geotools

Tags: java, csv, attributes, shapefile, geotools

Passing attributes of an imported CSV file to an imported shape. Shape as well as the csv were saved in collections.

hier ist meine Methode:

```
public SimpleFeatureCollection linkCsvShp(SimpleFeatureCollection sfColl) {
        // Iterate through the features of the Shapefile data source and update the attributes
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator it = sfColl.features()) {
            DefaultFeatureCollection newSfc = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature sf = it.next();
                String shpKeyAttribute = (String) sf.getAttribute("SCH_SG");
                try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> csvFeatures = csvCollection.features()) {
                    while (csvFeatures.hasNext()) {
                        SimpleFeature csvFeature = csvFeatures.next();
                        Object csvAttribute = csvFeature.getAttribute("SCH_GEM");
                        if (csvAttribute != null && csvAttribute.equals(shpKeyAttribute)) {
                            // Update the attributes of the Shape feature
                            sf.setAttribute("GEM_TYP", csvFeature.getAttribute("GEM_TYP"));
                            sf.setAttribute("KREIS", csvFeature.getAttribute("KREIS"));
                            sf.setAttribute("REGION", csvFeature.getAttribute("REGION"));
                            sf.setAttribute("EINW_KL", csvFeature.getAttribute("EINW_KLASSE"));
                            newSfc.add(sf);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            it.close();
            setStatus("Das Punktfeature wurde erfolgreich erweitert!");
        }

     
        return sfColl;
    }
```

he result is after many attempts unfortunately always that the attributes are not added.
It is important to mention that the features of both collections are checked to see if a key attribute matches.

Does anyone perhaps have other solutions?

shapeload method:

```
java.net.URL shapeURL = pointFile.toURI().toURL();
            store = new ShapefileDataStore(shapeURL);
            store.setTryCPGFile(true);
            SimpleFeatureSource fSource = store.getFeatureSource();
            SimpleFeatureCollection sfColl = linkCsvShp(fSource.getFeatures());
```

csv loadmethod:

```
private FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> csvCollection;
public void loadCsv(String path) {
        Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        params.put("file", path);

        DataStore store;
        try {
            store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
            String typeName = store.getTypeNames()[0];
            FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = store.getFeatureSource(typeName);
            Filter filter = Filter.INCLUDE;

            csvCollection = source.getFeatures(filter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

yeah had it:
[shapefile attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulRFx.png)

Comment: Do those attributes exist in the shapefile? Please add the schemas of the 2 data sets

Comment: Please use the,edit button to update your question, I need to see the actual schema of the features

Comment: sry added the stuff to my question

Comment: does your shapefile schema (`FeatureType`) have an attribute called `GEM_TYP` ?